# How to create a loop where loop changes every post in custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How can I create a type of loop in WordPress where an image moves left or right for each post? I.e. first post image will be left, second post image will go right, third post image will go left, and so on...

i am attach image. Provide some code or examples

Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDy6.jpg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uiqj.png)

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies') );
$Inc = 1;

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   

        <?php if($Inc==1){ ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php }else if($Inc==2){ ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>


        <?php }else if($Inc==3){ ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }else if($Inc==4){ ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php 
        if($Inc==4){
            $Inc =1;
        }
        $Inc++;
        endwhile;       
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

```
    <?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'team') );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
  $Inc = 0; //start your counter
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $person_image = get_field('person_image');
    $person_description = get_field('person_description');
    ?>
        <?php if($Inc % 2 == 0){ //if $inc can be created by multiplying 2.?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <div>
                  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dot1.png" class="img-responsive dotimages">
                </div>
              </div> <!--.col-md-1 -->
              <div class="col-md-10 row">
                <div class="clientimagesarea">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div>
                      <img src="<?php echo $person_image; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block peopleimages">
                      <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="clienttext clienttextmarleft">
                      <?php echo $person_description; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                            <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/email-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon text-left"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                            <div class="emailid">abx@sitename.com</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                            <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/call-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon2 "></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                            <div class="emailid2">+41 79 777 66 45</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php //the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php }else { //it cant?>
          <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="deviderline">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="row clientimagesarea">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="clienttext">
                    <p>
                      <?php echo $person_description; ?>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row iconmarginleft">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                          <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/email-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon text-left"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                          <div class="emailid">abx@sitename.com</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddmargin0">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
                          <div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/call-icon2.png" class="img-responsive clientemailicon2 "></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-8">
                          <div class="emailid2">+91 1234567890</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $person_image; ?>" class="img-responsive center-block peopleimages clienttextmarleft">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <div>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/dot3.png" class="img-responsive dotimage3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
        $Inc++;
        endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: You can achieve that using css flex. Consider adding code that you have tried

Comment: You can also do it with php. Basically, add a `$counter` before the `while loop` and inside the loop use `if ($counter % 2 == 0 ){//Flip that shit}` and increment with `$counter++;`

Comment: Stender this is my code

Comment: This is my html code. - @Varsha Dhadge

Comment: This is my html code. - @Stender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic makes sense, I haven't tested this, but this should flib every second item with your code.

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'case_studies') );


if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
$Inc = 0; //start your counter
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   

        <?php if($Inc % 2 == 0){ //if $inc can be created by multiplying 2.?>
        <div class="col-sm-3  nopadding">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php }else { //it cant?>
            <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                <h2><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></h2>
            </div>

    <?php }
    $Inc++; //increment the counter
    endwhile;       
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: forgot to flip it, changed it

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below code

```
<div class="row">


<?php
$category = get_the_category();
$slug = $category[0]->slug;
$args = array(
  'post_type'  => 'post',
  'category_name'=>$slug,
  'posts_per_page'=> 1,

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>


   <div class="container">
       <div class="img-box">
           <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID());?>
           </img>
       </div>
       <div class="content">
           <?php 
                 $content = get_the_content();
                 echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 25, '' );
             ?>
       </div>
   </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

```css
.container{
display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.img-box{
  width:40%;
}
img{
 max-width:100%;
}
.content{
  width:60%
}
.container:nth-child(even){
  flex-direction: row-reverse;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="img-box">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="img-box">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice CSS based solution!

Comment: Thanks varsha Dhadge

Answer (score -1):

You have to register your post-type like :

```
add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
/**
 * Register a book post type.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
 */
function codex_book_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Books', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Book', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Books', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Book', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Book', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Books', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Books:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No books found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No books found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
                'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
```

and after the loop is :

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'book', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content() . the_thumbnails();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

then you can to make some custom fields 
i let you working on it

Comment: This doesn't flip anything... the question is not about how to create a CPT.